# Using wp_remote_get to work with XML in WordPress

Tags: php, xml, wordpress

I suspect I'm missing something really basic and obvious, so apologies in advance!

I had been using `simple_xml_load` to work with an XML file, but my client's hosting provider blocks the loading of external files through this method. I'm now trying to rebuild my work using the `wp_remote_get` function built into WordPress.

Here's my code (note: the key and shelter ID are generic in this example):

```
$url = "http://api.petfinder.com/shelter.getPets?key=1234&count=20&id=abcd&status=A&output=full";
$pf_xml = wp_remote_get( $url );
$xml = wp_remote_retrieve_body($pf_xml);
```

Using this, I can retrieve an array of all the data I need, but I cannot figure out how to target specific data. Here is what's output from `print_r($xml)`:

```
<petfinder xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://api.petfinder.com/schemas/0.9/petfinder.xsd">
    <header>
        <version>0.1</version>
        <timestamp>2013-03-09T15:03:46Z</timestamp>
        <status>
        <code>100</code>
        <message/>
        </status>
    </header>
    <lastOffset>5</lastOffset>
    <pets>
        <pet>
            <id>13019537</id>
            <name>Jordy</name>
            <animal>Dog</animal>
        </pet>
        <pet>
            <id>13019888</id>
            <name>Tom</name>
            <animal>Dog</animal>
        </pet>
    </pets>
</petfinder>
```

If I wanted to `echo` the status code, for example, how would I do that? Using simplexml, I would write `$xml->header->status->code`. I can't seem to figure out what the code structure is to do something similar with arrays using `wp_remote_get`.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your code so far does retrieve the XML as string:

```
$url      = "http://api.petfinder.com/shelter.getPets?key=1234&count=20&id=abcd&status=A&output=full";
$response = wp_remote_get($url);
$body     = wp_remote_retrieve_body($response);
```

To load a string (instead of a URL) into a `SimpleXMLElement` as you did before with [`simplexml_load_file`](http://php.net/simplexml_load_file) (you didn't show the concrete code so I assume you did it this way based on your description) you now need to load the string with [`simplexml_load_string`](http://php.net/simplexml_load_string) instead:

```
$xml  = simplexml_load_string($body);
$code = $xml->header->status->code;
```

I slightly changed your variable names (especially with the `wp_remote_*` functions) to make it more clear for what those variables carry.